How to deal with a possibly autistic colleague that seems to be fixated on me
At the moment I (F) have a colleague (M) that works now for 5 months at my workplace.
At the beginning naturally like everyone else you don't know someone yet and need time to get to know one another. I am now at the stage that I concluded that his behaviour is somewhat different and it looks to me he has autistic or narcissistic traits. I am confused and I am not sure how to proceed further.
Professionally, I am very irritated by his behaviour and what he says.
My colleague tends to talk very loudly and he tends to tell the same story repeatedly to different colleagues. I listened three times to his story for roughly one hour each and consequently I was then late at home. That's on me. The weird thing that puzzled me at the beginning is that he always comes to me or another colleague whenever he needs to vent or complain, but besides that he just ignores me like I don't exist which I found weird and not respectful at the beginning, but now it's a blessing. He also says sometimes demeaning things to me and also looks somehow down on my one other female colleague. So, I also get the feeling that he might me a bit misogynistic.
Personally, the issue is he said and did some stuff to me which I found very uncomfortable, and I am now ignoring him. I am not sure whether his behaviour is due to his autism or maybe it's something else. However, I don't feel safe with him.
He always seems fixated on me, since I feel his stares sometimes on me and I feel super uncomfortable with that. He also did once a weird thing. We had a standup meeting in a big room. I felt his clothes touching my back, so I shifted my body away from him, but then he moved to me once again. The same cycle repeated 4 or 5 times and I just kinda gave up.
I felt super uncomfortable by that and I was wondering whether it's due his autism or whether it was sexual harassment.
I don't want to accuse him yet, since he might be just oblivious, but to me it felt super uncomfortable. Apparently another time I was with him and a few other colleagues, he made some jokes which could be interpreted as sexual harassment, but since he doesn't quite read the social cues, it might have been just to make himself funny which wasn't a successful attempt. My other colleague who was also there told me that he found the remarks of my assumingly autistic colleague weird and inappropriate.
I am now thus a stage that I am ignoring him and I only meet with him when there are other colleagues around.
I am wondering whether there are other things I can do, since I always get a dreading and unsafe feeling when I hear or see him.
Edit: it feels weird and invalidating to see that I get attacked for asking this question from some people. For me it feels a bit like victimblaming which doesn't really help and only maks me feel bad for asking this question.
The rest I want to thank and I will be trying to be direct and clear in my communication. In case he goes further, I will go to HR.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There's a chatroom for the question already please take any further discussion there. Since I can't migrate the discursive comments a second time I've purged them and locked the comments on this post.

The Netherlands have very good employee protection and culturally this type of behavior is not acceptable. You should find good support from your colleagues and company,

... and did some stuff to me which I found very uncomfortable

Your best bet here is to call out the behavior right there when it happens. Be loud, be firm, be clear: "Stop doing/saying this. It is inappropriate and makes me feel uncomfortable". The more people hear it, the better. And yes, that's difficult to do but it is the most effective way. If you need to practice in front of a mirror and/or with a friend.

and I am now ignoring him.

That's a good start. If he initiates any (unwanted) interaction, your goal is to make this as unpleasant as possible for him, while still being professional. Calling out his behavior in public will do this.

I felt his clothes touching my back,

Again: Call it out: "Please stop touching me"

I was wondering whether it's due his autism

That is not your problem and not your concern. Unless you are officially asked to provide "accommodation" you should treat him the same and with the same expectations as everyone else. You should focus on stopping the unwanted behavior, the causes for the behavior are actually not relevant for you: that would be for HR to deal with.

Keep notes. After every questionable interaction write down the details (when, where, what exactly was said/done, who else was around to corroborate if needed, etc)
Read up on local laws and company policies. In most countries & companies this well regulated and there are clear guidelines of what to do and how to elevate and get help. The Netherlands should be very good this way
Consider involving your manager or HR, but NOT before doing your homework (see bullet 2)


Thank you for the exact steps which I can take. Unfortunately I cannot upvote your comment. For some reason I feel bad, but like you said  and another person. Of another person makes me feel uncomfortable, I should tell clearly at that moment that my colleague is making me feel uncomfortable regardless of the cause (that might be autism in his case) I already feel much better. So I am going to practice in front of the window and try to tell him directly.

Assuming that the person involved is autistic, This advice will only confuse and embarass them. If you want them fired, go to HR NOW. If you want them to stop AND they are autistic tell them clearly without being "in front of as many people as possible". Decide if "not my problem" means get him fired - a reasonable response. Or to improve the situaction.

@DogBoy37: do not assume that the person is autistic unless there is a communication from HR that you should do so including behavioral guidelines , expectations and required accommodation. Medical information is typically confidential and protected. It's not your business to diagnose your coworkers. It IS your business to behave professionally and to expect everyone around you to do the same.

@Hilmar if someone is on the spectrum enough that it affects their work behavior, it is obvious. HR doesn't need to say that an employee uses a wheelchair for people to understand to not block the hallways. If the OP's situation is dealing with a creep, get him fired. If the person is autistic, the situation likely can be very quickly fixed by simple conversation. I am not a fan of adding HR, that is escalation. That is IMHO (which is worth a grain of sand in the mojave).

"you should treat him the same and with the same expectations as everyone else", on some levels you're right, but on others you're not. Autistic people view the world slightly different than neurotypical people, and in some cases you'll just have to bluntly tell them to stop doing something and why.

Also, ignoring him is not necessarily "a good start". People with autism don't always see social cues like being ignored, or if they do see them, they will not get the message you're trying to send. Be clear about the problem.

Also, in general, HR will have no business informing employees about medical conditions of other employees, unless explicitly at the request of said employee.

@DogBoy37 Whatever OP does is highly unlikely to get anyone fired. Firing anybody in the Netherlands is really difficult (even in comparison to many other EU member states, let alone the US).

@MarkRotteveel: the problem here is the following "Who determines whether the co-worker is autistic or not?" If everyone starts guessing what medical or mental issues everyone else might have, we end up with a total mess of assumptions, speculations and rumors. The OP thinks the that this may be the case, but they cannot be sure. It's NOT the OPs job to diagnose this. If the co-worker requires accommodation (which is a well defined legal term) HR needs to set guidelines on communicate them. If not, then you should treat them like everyone else.

@Hilmar Sure, we're working on an assumption of the OP, based on something another coworker said. The only one who can determine that the person is autistic is a GGZ psychologist, and the only one who can tell people this (or ask someone to do it on their behalf) is the colleague in question. But if the OP is autistic, then being direct helps, and even if they are not, we Dutch are a relatively direct culture, so telling someone to stop something will work pretty well in that case compared to ignoring things and hoping it goes away.

I'd say telling someone whose behaviour makes one uncomfortable in an unambiguous and direct (but if possible neither unfriendly) fashion what behaviour exactly one asks them to stop and what exactly to do instead ("please keep at least $this_much distance from me") is a good next step after moving away and ignoring didn't help. Regardless of autism, laymen diagnoses etc. - so IMHO right now: no need to actually wonder why the colleague behaves the way they do. (I may be biased by coming from a culture that anyways values unambiguity and rather direct blunt communication)

... but regardless of how much sugarcoating the local culture asks for, since already two more sugarcoated behavioural approaches by  OP did not yield the required result, it is IMHO time to escalate to more unambiguous statements of what you need (which is unambiguously inside polite behaviour), and that they have to behave accordingly.

@Hilmar, the question is not whether the colleague is autistic or not. The question is what OP needs to do to change the colleague's unwanted behaviour. You don't need a medical diagnosis for this. If the colleague has some aspects of autistic behaviour, and OP manages to change their behaviour, then everything is fine.

It just occurred to me... Two cases: You have an autistic colleague, who doesn't mean anything bad, but just doesn't get social clues. The blunt statement "don't do this" tells him what to do and he doesn't see it as blunt. Or your colleague isn't autistic, and what he does is all intentional. The blunt statement "don't do this" tells him what to do, and the bluntness is well deserved.

Autism isn't a binary, a have it or don't thing, I assume that you know that. This person's autism can't be determined by random people on the internet.
Speaking as parent with twins on the spectrum and a business own with an employee whose autism drastically affects his social skills, BE DIRECT.
Do not be concerned about hurting feelings. Just be direct, firm, as soon as a situation occurs. Explain that the behavior is not correct and to not do it again.
Stay as cool as you can. Try to remember if he could understand social cues, it wouldn't happen in the first place.
He isn't likely intending anything bad. If he keeps doing it, then go to HR.
One thing to remember. You are likely talking to a person that can't extrapolate when it comes to social / interpersonal situatuations. So, be very clear in setting guardrails in what is allowed and what is not allowed.
Example: Come to my desk during working hours to ask a specific question. During stand-up meetings stay at least 3 meters away from me.
Ultimately, you shouldn't have to feel uncomfortable at work from someones behavior. That is a given.

I have some autistic friends. They know they are bad at reading social cues, and appreciate explicit feedback when they're overstepping boundaries. So I second the advice to be direct about it, while trying to be sympathetic. Think of it as a form of blindness or deafness; not their fault, but it will cause them to make mistakes; calmly correct the mistakes and move on. If they aren't willing to accept correction, that's time to have their manager council them about appropriate workplace behavior.

Yes. This. Autism is a social disability, not a mental one. Talk to him with direct and objective language. But remember, it is a DISABILITY. Expecting an autistic person to observe subtle social cues is the same as screaming at a deaf person because they can't year you.

"Don't be concerned about hurt feelings" — DogBoy37 is correct. OP should draft what she wants to tell this coworker and be blunt. Not rude, blunt. Polite communication often relies on kind and subjective language to dull the edges. Do the opposite of that. Be logical, direct, and no-nonsense.

It's the Netherlands anyway. Direct feedback already is the norm, you're not even assuming autism there.

If he his indeed autistic, it might help to explicitly point it out to him at the time he does something that it is either not appropriate or bothering you. Moving away or ignoring it is not enough to make him realize that what he's doing is inappropriate. Pointing out explicitly (providing clarity) the problematic behaviour and why it bothers you will help him understand and correct his actions.
Telling him what he needs to do instead will also help, but don't sugarcoat it. For example, in the situation where he is standing too close to you, tell him to stand back and not stand in your personal space. Don't say that you'd prefer if he'd give you some space, or something similar, because that just expresses your preference and leaves the decision with him and can also easily be misinterpreted by him in other ways.
Waiting until later (e.g. to do it in private), can produce a too large disconnect between the action and the correction, which might not make him realize the problem. And if you do do it later, make sure you are as clear as possible in identifying the problem, and when it happened.
However, if you feel (too) shy or unable to tell them this directly, don't hesitate to ask your manager for help in addressing this, or some other coworker that is (regularly) present when these behaviours occur. You can also talk to one of the "vertrouwenspersonen" (Google translates it as confidential counselors, but I'm not sure if that translation covers it) that your company is legally required to have (if it has 50 employees or more) exactly for these types of scenarios.
Others have said to go to HR immediately, but I think that if this colleague is indeed autistic that might be an extreme escalation, and might take longer to resolve things than confronting them or having your manager confront them. On the other hand, if this guy is just a creep, instead of socially awkward/oblivious, such escalation might be the better course of action.
Keep in mind: HR might redirect you to the "vertrouwenspersoon" anyway.

Thank you. For some reason I have difficulties talking about my boundaries to other people. So I will try that out that. Based on the reaction of my colleague, can I derive what the motivation is? In case he is indeed autistic, he will probably accept it. If he gets defensive, can I derive that he has other motives?

One important thing about autism is that people with autism have problems getting hints, but are perfectly fine  being told what you mean. Don't give hints. Like "you are always there when I come from my coffee break". I would get the hint that you don't like it. Someone with autism would see that you stated a true fact. Tell them "I don't want you to be at my desk when I come from my coffee break". I'd think that is rude. Someone with autism would understand exactly what you say and stay away from your desk. And don't worry about motivation, only about what actually happens.

@Musashi17: Trying to decode inner motives is a waste of your time and energy, and potentially unhealthy to your mental state. Avoid it.

@gnasher729 that's interesting. I unfortunately don't have much experienced with autistic people, so I guess that's also a good learning experience. I have to tell very bluntly otherwise he wouldn't get it. I will try that out

@Musashi17 As Daniel says, it's hard to assign intent, and you shouldn't. Just keep it factual on how his interactions with you make you feel, and what you'd like them to change. Don't try to infer anything about their motivations. It doesn't help, and only clouds the issue.

@Musashi17 Are you Dutch or do you come from a different culture? That could be the reason, as other cultures are often much less direct than what's usual in the Netherlands.

@TooTea I am half Dutch and half Japanese. My personality is a bit mixed. I am indirect for a dutch person, but direct compared to japanese standard. So that might indeed  explain that I find it uncomfortable to be very direct or blunt.

@Musashi17 I recommend that you practice this with a Dutch friend, until you get more comfortable. That will be hard work. (There was a TV show where they invited 20 people each from different countries to a free holiday, telling them that they would be filmed and interesting things would be happening, with two paid actors in every group. Question: How do people react if someone jumps the queue at the hotel bar? The two Japanese actors found it 100% impossible for them to jump the queue, even knowing that it wasn't real but just an experiment. )

Autism
Other answers have covered what you should do, but I just wanted to comment on autism itself. Many people in the community make the important observation that "autism is an explanation, not an excuse". What that means is that people on the ASD spectrum are fully responsible for their actions and behavior. They don't get a free pass to do whatever they feel like because they have a neurodivergent (ND) diagnosis. You do not have an obligation to "accommodate" them by allowing them to do whatever they want. In fact, doing so does neither of you any favors. You will build up resentment, and they will learn the wrong social cues about their behavior and get in trouble with other people who are less tolerant.
The only accommodation you should give to ND individuals is adjusting your communication style. As others have pointed out, neurotypical (NT) people will often say things indirectly and couch them in metaphor to avoid giving offense. But ND folks prefer you to just say what you need to say directly, even if the bluntless feels offensive by your NT expectations. ND folks often struggle with metaphors and tend to take things more literally, so they actually prefer bluntness. Sometimes, they do not know that something they are doing is inappropriate or bothersome to others. If you tell them directly, they will often appreciate the bluntness and will hopefully change their behavior.
Accommodation
Fortunately, being blunt about setting your personal boundaries is also appropriate for NT coworkers, although there is a greater risk of offense and resentment. I think it is reasonable to tell the coworker once or twice to stop/modify their objectionable behavior. You should, of course always document the behavior (date/time/location/other coworkers present), and escalate to HR if it continues. If you wish to accommodate a perceived neurodivergence, do so by explicitly stating the undesired behavior and what you expect going forward. Do not use euphemisms or figures of speech or idioms. Use the most clinically appropriate and precise language that you can. This includes not just physical touching, but sexually inappropriate jokes and even discriminatory (misogynistic) behavior. This might make you uncomfortable, so if you don't think you can handle it, then just engage HR immediately to assist.
If it helps, think of your coworker as someone who came from a different culture and hasn't learned all the ins and outs of your culture. They most likely don't mean any harm, but simply have not received adequate feedback on what behaviors are acceptable or not. Unfortunately, they have probably also picked up on bad behavior from other coworkers and determined that this is acceptable behavior. If they protest: "Well, Ted does this too!" then just reply: "If Ted does it to me, we will be having a meeting with HR soon after. He will get no special treatment." As long as they believe there are rules in place for everyone and they are enforced fairly, there is a good chance they will respect the boundaries. Of course, each person is a unique individual, so YMMV.

People are talking about HR. I think that is the wrong escalation. Talk to your supervisor/boss/leader. That is the natural next step here. Someone or something is making your work life uncomfortable and less productive, that is textbook "talk to your leader"-material.
I agree that this sounds like a case for talking to the employee rep, or perhaps even HR, but those things come after talking to your boss. A good leader should be grateful to hear about this kind of sand in the machinery, and motivated to fix it.


I am wondering whether there are other things I can do, since I always get a dreading and unsafe feeling when I hear or see him.

Talk to the HR. Now.
An employee is making your uncomfortable and is bordering on some sort of sexual harassment when it's getting to touch state, don't wait any longer, just go and report it with HR. Same with all the sexism and misogyny, it's no on you to take it, or to correct the employee - that's what HR is for.
I don't understand the other answers here at all. You hear some office rumour that the person may be autistic - it doesn't matter, and it's not your place to act upon. If HR then wants to ask you to be more accommodating to them, do that, but that's not going to allow the person to touch you intentionally (with clothes or body), that definitely won't be part of it.

I do think it's worth the OP's while to try and be more direct in her feedback to this colleague. They may indeed just not get the hint and need a clearly worded setting of boundaries. Saying so is more socially acceptable in The Netherlands than it might be elsewhere.
That said: yes, going to HR is also reasonable. A colleague getting this close to you physically, is not socially acceptable.

@KatinkaHesselink It's an option to provide feedback, but if the only reason you do it is because of the ongoing "autism" rumor/excuse, don't. Just go to HR.

I second @KatinkaHesselink's comment. I've unfortunately been the guy who unknowingly interacted in a very awkward way with a female colleague (although nothing as extreme as the question), and after excusing myself and having a talk with her, we figured out everything. She just had to point out my reaction was inappropriate. If that doesn't work, HR.

@Clockwork I am glad it worked out for you, but also you have to realize that you don't deserve for OP, or anyone else there, to give you that chance; going right to HR is a perfectly fine response and that must be made clear. Standing up myself is also what I would personally do, but then I am loud, brass and unashamed, many people do not want to handle that confrontation themselves.

Just to be sure, when you say "you don't deserve for OP", you mean OP doesn't deserve to have to endure it any longer?

@Clockwork I mean that OP owes the offending party nothing.

@AidaPaul Thanks for the clarification. A part of me was still stuck in what I did back then and I had read that initial sentence as an accusatory pointed finger, and your second comment clarified that for me.

Aida, there was a guy in a wheelchair, and he was absolutely in my way. It offended me. I owe that guy in the wheelchair nothing. This guy is a colleague. He most likely has a disability that makes things hard for him. If you think you "owe him nothing", maybe your employer owes you nothing either. In the USA you would owe him "reasonable accommodations". In the Netherlands most likely too.

@gnasher729 Right, rumors of ausim == person in a wheelchair. Do you want a hat for your straw man?

What strawman? Any kind of disability can be inconvenient for others but requires "reasonable accomodation" in civilised countries.

@AidaPaul: in the described situation of 2 failed communication attempts, "OP owes the offender nothing" is IMHO not a very useful position. OP has a problem that needs to be solved, i.e. OP needs the co-worker to behave. We don't know more than some rumor-level speculations why the co-worker may be behaving as they do. But we know that the previous 2 communication attempts by OP did not lead to the required result. Even if one agrees that OP owes nothing, (in)actions suggested by this approach cannot realistically be expected to improve the relationship with the co-worker.

@cbeleitesunhappywithSX How is going to HR an inaction exactly?

OTOH, as @gnasher729 says, we owe reasonable accomodation for disabilities. In addition, people with disabilities also have the right to privacy in the sense that they do not have to disclose disability/health related things to co-workers. What is reasonable will likely always be a trade-off. But "OP owes nothing" is a position that asks disabled to people to trade in their privacy for getting some accomodation. Please note that this is not a volontary trade-off, and it is one that will repeatedly be forced onto the same people. However, it would also be possible to argue that giving OP's ...

@cbeleitesunhappywithSX That person is not disabled, it's rumors of disability by people not qualified to diagnose it. Feel like you want to post your own answer tho, go ahead.

... co-worker "accomodation" in the form of unambiguous communication is anyways worth while: a) with or without autism, an unambiguous statement of what behavior is required may lead to the desired result. b) the small cost of one more communication cycle before escalating to HR  protects the privacy of (unknown but existing) people whose disability requires such accomodation: where such steps are taken, they don't need to disclose their disabiliy. (For me, this alone would be sufficient reason) And c) last but not least, it may be required without OP being aware of this since the co-worker..

...may actually have a disability that requires such accomodation.

@AidaPaul: going to HR is action, and I fully agree with you that it is among the reasonable actions OP can take. But the position "OP owes him nothing" also allows the conclusion that the co-worker "should know how to behave by himself". I may be emphasizing this because OP writes of ignoring the co-worker and "giving up moving away" which are such inactions in line with the "owes noting" position, but which also did not work. And it is a position that easily puts collateral damage on actually disabled people - that's all I wanted to point out.

A few years ago, a female colleague had joined a company at which I was working. At some point during one of our conversations, I had said something bluntly, which I didn't know was an inappropriate thing to say. Suffice to say, she looked visibly angry and asked me if I thought that was an appropriate thing to say. It took me a few weeks to muster the courage to excuse myself and explain why I reacted the way I did without knowing it wasn't appropriate. We had a little talk, she explained to me why it wasn't an appropriate thing to say, and from then on we resumed interacting in a professional way.
I'm not on the spectrum. Since I grew up with a different lifestyle than most of the others during their childhood, I've had to learn social cues which are obvious for others but with which I am unfamiliar. I may say things and behave in ways that people find inappropriate without knowing it. My colleagues got used to letting me know about it when it happens, and I've also learned what may be inappropriate, so things are a lot smoother now.
If a colleague is behaving in a way that you find inappropriate towards you, there's a chance they might be as clueless as I was, so it might be worth pointing it out. If that doesn't work, you may refer to some of the other answers which talk about approaching HR.

With that being said, none of what I did, no matter how awkward, was anywhere as close as what is being described in the question, so HR might be a better solution since harassment is involved.

I agree with previous answers and comments saying that focusing on his possible diagnosis is not going to help. I have been in your place where I want to think the best of people and I excuse their behaviour too. Sometimes it's hard to accept someone is crossing a boundary because when a boundary is set it is us who have to take action to enforce it. It feels unfair that someone else crosses a line but we have to "make a fuss" or leave, but the number one person you can count on is you.
The first suggestion I would give is practicing "grey rocking". It's a technique for handling difficult, overwhelming people. The basic idea is to be as boring as possible, only answering with the most minimal information in most neutral tone -  not angry, not pleasant, neutral. You can find out more by looking up the term "grey rock technique".
The second suggestion is just a repetition of what everyone else has said - call him out in the moment, immediately. If he stands too close - immediately state "Brian, please stand further away". If he is staring - "Brian, did you need something?". If he starts a monologue - "Brian, I am busy/need to go, can you send it over an email?".
If I can be frank - I'm not too sure he will stop because you call him out and you probably have the same suspicion. However, this draws attention of any colleague in the vicinity and they will begin to see the pattern too. This will help with step 3.
The third step I would suggest is what Aida has already mentioned - consult HR. Don't bring up diagnosis rumours. You don't even have to file a complaint per se. Unfortunately HR works more for the company than for the employees, but it doesn't mean they won't help - they'll help when it benefits the company. Call me paranoid, but I would dip my toes by requesting advice on how to handle a coworker that goes on 1+h non work related monologues. His name goes on their radar and you get an idea how does the HR department work in this company.
You might feel more comfortable disclosing and reporting the harassment when the pattern has been established by calling him out and when you have had contact with HR and have gotten to know how they work. It's absolutely normal to be in a state of overwhelm when you are his main target and no one else notices what is happening. So stick to 3 steps:

Grey Rock if he approaches you
Call him out to establish a pattern
Get comfortable with HR

See, he is free to stop at any stage - when you show no interest, when you call him out again and again. If he doesn't stop and you're left to report the harassment case to HR there's no one left to blame but himself.
